# How to alias a hostname on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, hosts, localhost, alias

In a nutshell, I would like to be able to open a browser and open `local.example.com` but it actually loads `http://localhost/path/to/example.com/`

I am using Mac OSX 10.5, and not afraid to get my hands dirty with the terminal :)

I use Apache as my local server.

Comment: Are you trying to serve web pages to the outside world, or are you only expecting the http://local.example.com URL to work for your machine?

Comment: Just for my own machine. It gets tiresome typing/remembering the full filepath to my local copy of whatever websites I'm working on.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Just to be clear, I'm basing this on the assumption that you really do want http://local.example.com to load the literal web page http://localhost/path/to/example.com. In other words, this will only work for this machine.  If, on the other hand, you're trying to serve web pages to the outside world using your Mac OS X machine, then that's a different question.

First, add a new line to your `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1   local.example.com
```

You can do this by running the command `sudo nano /etc/hosts`, add this line to the end, then save it by pressing Ctrl-X, Y.

How you actually redirect/alias the address http://local.example.com to http://localhost/path/to/example.com/ depends on which web server you're using.  Assuming you're using Apache:

If you want the user's browser to show local.example.com, then you want to set up a [virual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) and your `httpd.conf` file should have something like the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName local.example.com
DocumentRoot /www/path/to/example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

If, on the other hand, you want the web browser's location bar to change to http://localhost/path/to/example.com/, then instead you will want to [use mod_rewrite to create a redirect](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^local\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         http://localhost/path/to/example.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: This won't go to a certain path though

Comment: @John you're right, fixed.

Comment: If the desired "alias" were `https://localhost/path/to/example.com`, i.e. `HTTPS`, not `HTTP`, would this solution still apply?

Comment: @KevinMeredith that's not possible. The browser has to know that it's talking HTTPS. It might be possible with a HTTP 302 redirect, which in Apache is called `Redirect`. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect

Comment: /etc/hosts usually gets overwritten if you're using a VPN though